# Burned iso to USB, wiped entire hard drive how ever, Ubuntu doesn't fully install

Tags: lts

Downloaded the 64 bit variant
Currently have Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS burned on a USB flash drive

When installing I chose to while everything ony hard drive (leaving windows and wanted nothing to be left behind).
After installation finishes, my PC reboots (using my hard drive to boot from). How ever I'm greeted with

"Try Ubuntu w/out installing"
"Install Ubuntu"
Ect.

This is my 4th time trying to install Ubuntu and each time I'm greeted with the same start up screen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have actually removed the flash drive before powering on the machine to verify that there's no way it's reading it, right?

Answer (score 1):

The flash drive has to be removed from the USB port before booting into your Ubuntu Installation.